# Unable to assign role to service account in gcp

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-automl

I'm able to create a service account but facing issues while assigning a role to the service account. Here is the approach I'm using

```
CloudResourceManager cloudResourceManagerService = createCloudResourceManagerService(clientId,
                clientSecret);

        GetIamPolicy getrequest = cloudResourceManagerService.projects().getIamPolicy(projectId,
                new GetIamPolicyRequest());

        Policy response = getrequest.execute();

//Modification to policy        

        List<String> members = response.getBindings().get(0).getMembers();
        members.add("serviceAccount:name@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
        response.getBindings().get(0).setMembers(members);
```

//          =================Set policy========================

```
         String resource = "projects/" + projectId + "/serviceAccounts/" +
                 "name@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

        SetIamPolicyRequest requestBody = new SetIamPolicyRequest().setPolicy(response);
        SetIamPolicy setrequest = cloudResourceManagerService.projects().setIamPolicy(resource, requestBody);
        Policy newResponse = setrequest.execute();
```

This code is not giving any error but also not setting a role for the provided service account.

Comment: Policies cannot be directly assigned to a project resource. You must first read the existing policy (even if empty), update the policy and then update the project resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are calling [projects.serviceAccounts.setIamPolicy](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/setIamPolicy), and because you specifically are passing the serviceAccount, you are only granting the service account editor role *on itself*.

If you want the service account to be an editor on the *project* you must call [projects.setIamPolicy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/setIamPolicy) and the resource you want to specify should be the project itself.

As John Hanley says, you will also need to do this as a read-modify-write cycle as [described here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#programmatic).